# Live Silverlight app won't display the data

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, silverlight

I have got a silverlight application, it works fine locally and all the data with displayed on the application but when I publish the same version to Live, most of the fields on the application will not display the data.

I have checked everything, stored procs, connection string and all other possible stuff but some of the fields won't display the data at all. The application uses the stored proc, when I run the same on the server returns data properly.

I have tried all possibilities, but couldn't find any solution, does anyone have any idea about this.

Thanks

Comment: post some code. XAML. how is the data accessed? silverlight does not support direct data access. You need to go thru WCF or something. post the relevant code or at least screenshots of the problem.

Comment: how to add screenshots here? I dont have any idea on that. FYI, it works perfectly fine on my development and UAT servers.